# How to use Vue.js element without npm?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Is it possible to use a component without having `npm`?

I'm trying to make https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-bootstrap4-table#4-basic-usage work but it fails.

I can't import component inside `html` file.

Tried:

```
import VueBootstrap4Table from 'vue-bootstrap4-table';

app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: [{
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxebLj1s/).

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `import VueBootstrap4Table from 'vue-bootstrap4-table';` a) you need webpack (or another bundler) to resolve the import, b) webpack will try to resolve the import from the `node_modules` folder (which you won't have without npm). Just **use npm**. It's the way to go. Any attempt on using any modern packages or frameworks without npm is bound to fail.

Comment: @connexo Actually modern browsers can handle those `import` statements if they're inside a module and not a JS import. The path has to be a valid URL, standard URL rules apply (absolute, relative, etc...), the file extension should be `.mjs`, and you can use a tool like `unpkg.me` to get a URL to what is normally a node package. I'm not saying I'd recommend this for a production project but the question doesn't sound like it's asking about production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove:

```
import VueBootstrap4Table from 'vue-bootstrap4-table';
```

and

```
...,
components: {
  VueBootstrap4Table
}
```

from the bottom of your Vue instance - by adding the CDN reference, it's already included.

Then lastly, looks like you were missing the bootstrap css for this table.  I added it as a dependency in the fiddle.

check it out:

https://jsfiddle.net/u4twL905/